# addTailwindPlugin is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, tailwind-css

I can't compile my code anymore because I get this error in my console:

`An unhandled exception occurred: addTailwindPlugin is not a function`

I don't know what happened actually, but I looked into my `webpack.config.js` file and there's another error with ESLint: `Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved`.

That's really weird. Here's the config:

```js
const { addTailwindPlugin } = require("@ngneat/tailwind");
const tailwindConfig = require("./tailwind.config.js");

module.exports = (config) => {
  addTailwindPlugin({
    webpackConfig: config,
    tailwindConfig,
    patchComponentsStyles: true
  });
  return config;
};
```

Comment: This might be a version problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same error.  For me it was because I had upgraded my project to ngneat 7.0 and Angular 11.2, which has built-in support for tailwindcss:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/73b409881f71a8235769a345356dcde3c568d0c3

I was able to resolve the error by removing the reference to the custom webpack.config.js from angular.json, since the tailwind plugin was the only customization that I had.